# SQL Server Agent job fails but stored procedure works in open session

Tags: sql-server, excel

Looking to update a table with the data from excel.  The job error is;

> "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7399)  Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
>
> [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7303).

Runs fine with open SSMS Session. Here is the stored procedure;

```
if object_id ('MyTable') is null    
create table MyTable    
    (ForecastItem itemtype, PlanningBill int, OrderedItem itemtype)     
    
truncate table MyTable    
    
insert into MyTable 
select *      
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',     
    'Excel 12.0;Database=\\Myserver\Public$\Forecast Generator\Forecasting Generator.xls;HDR=YES',    
    'SELECT [planning BoM], [Planning Bill #], ItemCode FROM [Planning Bill CREF$]')
```

The job owner has domain privileges to the location of the excel file.

I am assuming there is a rights issue but everything looks ok.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: seems like a permission issue with your linked server setup

Comment: The job owner definitely is not equivalent stored procedure owner as well as not equivalent network credentials that your db server use to access file over network. I would start from switching on audit on Myserver for your excel file. At least you will see if any  user trying to open the file.

Comment: One of possible reason is your dbserver trying to open file with its service process credentials. For Network Service you will see something like MySQLServer$.